# JavaFX TextArea to ListView intergration

Tags: listview, console, textarea, javafx-8, textfield

1. Working on a timer app that prints out to the console while the app is running.
2. I want *all* the same information to print in the app's text area.
3. It will only print the current activity in the text area but it will not print all.
4. Tried to use ListView instead of TextArea but could not figure out how to intergrade it into the app. Is there a easier way to do this?
5. The image shows: arrow 2 "loggedMessages" = this only stores the last activity. arrow 3 is the console with all the activities logged.
   I want the loggedMessage area to display all the activities the console captures.

Here is the code:

[Image of Timer app fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b2K1.png)

```
public class Controller   {

@FXML private AnchorPane container;
@FXML private Label title;
@FXML private TextArea inputMessage;
@FXML private TextArea loggedMessages;


private Timeline mTimeline; 
private TimerAttempt mCurrentAttempt;  
private StringProperty mTimerText;



public Controller(){
    mTimerText = new SimpleStringProperty(); 
    setTimerText(0); 
}


public String getTimerText() {
    return mTimerText.get();
}

public StringProperty timerTextProperty() {
    return mTimerText;
}

public void setTimerText(String timerText) {
    this.mTimerText.set(timerText);
}
public void setTimerText(int remainingSeconds){
    int minutes = remainingSeconds / 60;
    int seconds = remainingSeconds % 60;
    setTimerText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
}


private void prepAttempt(AttemptKind kind ){
    reset();
        mCurrentAttempt = new TimerAttempt(kind, ""); 
        addAttemptStyle(kind);

        title.setText(kind.getTheDisplayName());
        setTimerText(mCurrentAttempt.getRemainingSeconds()); 

        mTimeline = new Timeline(); 
        mTimeline.setCycleCount(kind.getAmountOfSeconds()); 
        mTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e ->{
                mCurrentAttempt.tickDown();
                setTimerText(mCurrentAttempt.getRemainingSeconds()); 
        }));

    mTimeline. setOnFinished(e -> {
        saveCurrentAttempt(); 
        mApplause.play();
        prepAttempt(mCurrentAttempt.getTypeOfAttempt() == AttemptKind.STUDYING ?
                                                AttemptKind.BREAK : AttemptKind.STUDYING); 
    });
}

private void saveCurrentAttempt() {
    mCurrentAttempt.setMessage(inputMessage.getText()); 
    mCurrentAttempt.save();
    loggedMessages.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentAttempt));
     inputMessage.clear();
}


private void reset() {
    clearAttemptStyles();
    if (mTimeline != null && mTimeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
        mTimeline.stop();
}
}

private void addAttemptStyle(AttemptKind kind) {
    container.getStyleClass().add(kind.toString().toLowerCase());

}
private void clearAttemptStyles(){
    container.getStyleClass().remove("playing");
    for (AttemptKind kind : AttemptKind.values()){
        container.getStyleClass().remove(kind.toString().toLowerCase());

    }

}
```

//-----------------------Timer Class-------------------

```
  public class TimerAttempt {
    private String mMessage;
    private int mRemainingSeconds;
    private AttemptKind mTypeOfAttempt;


    public TimerAttempt(AttemptKind kind, String inputMessage) {
        mTypeOfAttempt = kind;
        mMessage = inputMessage;
        mRemainingSeconds = kind.getAmountOfSeconds();

   }

    public AttemptKind getTypeOfAttempt() {
        return mTypeOfAttempt;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public int getRemainingSeconds() {
        return mRemainingSeconds;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }

    public void tickDown() {
        mRemainingSeconds --;
    }

    public void save() {

        System.out.printf("LOGGED:  %s %n ", this); 
    }


        @Override
    public String toString() {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm;ss a");
        String formattedDate = timeStamp.format(date);

        return formattedDate +
                "\n Working on: " + mMessage +
                "\n During : " + mTypeOfAttempt + '\n';
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
loggedMessages.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentAttempt));
```

with

```
loggedMessages.appendText(String.valueOf(mCurrentAttempt));
```

The `TextArea` method `appendText(...)` appends text to the text area. The `TextArea` method `setText(...)` sets the text of the text area.

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thanks for the simple explanation.